# How to get information from an iframe which uses flash image slider using javascript?

Tags: javascript, flash, iframe

I am developing a Wordpress theme. In one page I have to use `iframe` to get content from another website. That page is an image slider and it uses flash for it. I don't have any idea about flash. It uses something like `AC_FL_RunContent`.

I need to get information of the images to show some text based on the image. I mean different text for different image. Is there any way, can I pull out the information like the name of the image from this `iframe`?

I have full access to the flash file too. But they are on different domain.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the source file(s) for the flash you might be able to work around the iFrame's sandbox by using a LocalConnection to a small, invisible proxy flash file in your template that runs subsequent JS calls. It would require you to make changes to the original image gallery and recompile it.

The model would be as follows:

1. Image gallery flash sends file name as a message over LocalConnection.
2. Proxy flash recieves message, uses ExternalInterface to call JS function on page.
3. JS function on page recieves function call from proxy flash and performs relevant actions.

[Adobe LiveDocs on using LocalConnection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html)

[Adobe LiveDocs on using ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)

It's not pretty I admit, but it's the only solution I can think of if the image gallery is a flash.

Comment: An iframe still has it's own non-penetrable sandbox, even if the contents in it reside on the same domain as the page hosting it. You would still need some kind of proxy between them. Although Flash isn't the ideal solution it will work, especially since it is what you already have. Flash will even allow cross-domain communication as long as the the reciever of the request is hosting a cross-domain policy file that allows access from the requesting domain.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access the content of an IFRAME that is pointing to another site. The [SOP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) will prevent that. It will be a security threat.

Cheers.

Comment: With this I can get access of an DOM, but can I use it in case of flash? I need to get the image name at least. There is no <div> or any HTML tag in that iframe. What to do in this case?

Comment: I have never used flash, sorry I cannot help you with that :(

Comment: Thanks anyway. You gave me some good piece of information. Cheers.